# Create table with other table data

Tags: sql, oracle

Following query works but i want with 2 fields

```
CREATE TABLE TOTAPPS (ANUM) AS SELECT a.A# FROM APPLICANT a.
```

This is work that

```
//TOTAPPS
ANUM
--------
```

if i want to create with 2 fields?

```
//Totapps
ANUM               NUMBER
---------------------------
```

how should i create the table? in order to get the correct out?
and the NUMBER is refer to the ANUM , for example

```
CREATE TABLE TOTAPPS (ANUM) AS SELECT a.A# FROM APPLICANT a,
   (NUMBER) AS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a.A#;
```

but it's failed to work.

Comment: please, could you write in English purpose of your query? you want to store A# column and .... what? count of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a column NUMBER is not correct as it is a reserved word. Assuming from your second query that you want to add to your table distinct values of a.A# and the count of these values in the table, you should try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TOTAPPS (ANUM, MYNUMBER) AS 
SELECT a.A#, COUNT(a.A#) FROM APPLICANT a GROUP BY a.A#;
```